# Mask to complete input

Tags: javascript, jquery, masking

Let's suppose I have the following constants declared:

```
const begin = '1234';
const end = '789';
```

and I have one html input with preset value='1234-56??-????-0987'

How can I setup a mask (using jQuery-Mask plugin, or not) to:

- When the user inserts any number (for example 7) on the input, the value becomes: `1234-567?-????-0987`
- If, after this user inserts '8', it becomes: `1234-5678-????-0987`
- When the user replaces all '?', then stop accepting inputs.
- If the user backspaces/erases any digit, the corresponding `?` appears again.

Currently I have this code:

```
const start = '123456';
const end = '0987';
const input = document.getElementById('entry-number');
input.addEventListener('input', () => 
{
    const mask = "******";
    const userInput = input.value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(start, "").replace(end, "");
    const newNumber = start + userInput + mask.slice(userInput.length) + end;
    input.value = newNumber;
});
```

But

1. It doesn't respect the mask with hyphens.
2. If I hit backspace, it completely bugs the input value.

Comment: Is it necessary to include the fixed parts ('123456' and '0987') inside the input field?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to maintain them. The value of the input is set by default with 1234-56??-????-0987... once the user type something, we just complete the question marks with what he types, until no question mark left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery [inputmask](https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/) plugin could be used to achieve this.

We would use the mask `1234-5699-9999-0\\987`. The `99-9999` pattern in (approximately) the middle indicates where arbitrary digits may be entered. The `\\9` indicates that this position will have a literal "9" and not an arbitrary digit. We can specify `?` as the placeholder value which will be used in the absence of any of the arbitrary digits that can be entered.

```js
$('#entry-number').inputmask({
  mask: '1234-5699-9999-0\\987',
  placeholder: '?'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/inputmask@5.0.8/dist/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>
<input id="entry-number">
```